# use $(this) instead of selector

Tags: jquery

How would I use $(this) instead of the full selector in the code below in the "if" statement. I tried a few different combination of "this" usage and none worked. Among them are...

```
if ($("this :selected").text().indexOf("[Subtract") >= 0){
if ($(this" :selected").text().indexOf("[Subtract") >= 0){
```

I am sure its gotta be something really simple, I just cannot figure it out today.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select[name^=SELECT___]").change(function() {
if ($("select[name^=SELECT___] :selected").text().indexOf("[Subtract") >= 0){
alert('');
}
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`find` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) on `$(this)` to find specific elements that are descendants of `this`:

```
$(this).find(":selected").text().indexOf("[Subtract")
```

Comment: .find() searches all the hierarchy

Comment: @Tudorizer: Just like the selector `select[name^=SELECT___] :selected`.

Comment: So which one would be better find or filter, hmmm looks like a trip to the jQuery docs

Comment: @user357034: My solution is equivalent to `select[name^=SELECT___] :selected` (note the space) while Tudorizer’s is equivalent to `select[name^=SELECT___]:selected` (note the missing space).

Comment: BTW, user357034, your two examples above are syntactically wrong. `this` is an object.

Comment: @Tudorizer: He asked us because all his attempts failed.

Comment: @Gumbo, yes. I'm just helping him out, so he's more careful in the future. Sometimes stuff like that gets really frustrating.

Comment: Well yes I know that otherwise I wouldn't be here :)

Comment: Using $(':selected', this) like suggested below is more efficient because it does not create a jquery wrapper over the context (which is not necessary)

Comment: @Andre - That's just not true. :o) As I stated in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933549/use-this-instead-of-selector/3933597#3933597), it gets turned around into the *exact* same structure as @Gumbo's answer. This happens after a bunch of tests run. After it gets turned around, it starts all over. So setting the context is less efficient. [Here's the source.](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L146)

Comment: @patrick, freak.. you're right, that's just stupid.. this might be where jquery could gain performance; instead of converting the context to an array with jquery context and then for each dom element in the array call Sizzle.find ...

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `this` as the context of the selector:

```
$(":selected",this)
```

But it ultimately just gets turned around [into @Gumbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933549/use-this-instead-of-selector/3933568#3933568). So that would be a little more efficient.

---

*Ultimately, I wouldn't use either.* If you actually need to selected `<option>`, this would be another approach:

```
this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].text.indexOf(...;
```

Since `this` is the `<select>` element, you use its `options` property which stores an Array of the options, and its `selectedIndex` property to get the selected one from the `options`.

Then you use the `<option>` element's `text` property to get the text.

More efficient this way.

Answer (score 2):

$(this).filter(':selected')

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: This is incorrect. `.filter()` will test only against the current set. Not any descendants.

Comment: I know. If what you said is the need, then .find() is the right answer.

Comment: If you know it is wrong, then why did you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(":selected", this)
```

This limits the ":selected" selector to the context of the "this" object.  More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery 'is' selector seems to do what you want although I haven't checked it: http://api.jquery.com/is/

```
if($(this).is(":selected").text().indexOf("[Subtract") >= 0){ ... }
```